# How can I remotely SSH into my PC which is behind a router-modem?

Tags: networking, ssh

I have a static IP address on my router-modem and I have a PC running Ubuntu which is connected to the router with an IP address allocated by DHCP.

I want to connect to that PC from a remote host via SSH. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If and how you can do this depends on your router.
The way I do it is:

1. I allocate a fixed/static address to my computer (make sure that the address you use is on the subnet used by you lan -- it will probably start `192.168.0`. Depending on your router you may have to either:

   (i) telling the router to allocate a fixed IP a the MAC address of your PC; or

   (ii) configuring the PC's IP address manually (and make sure that it is outside the range allocated by your routers DHCP server)
2. On the router, set up port forwarding. SSH uses TCP port 22, so you map port 22 on the router's WAN connection to port 22 on the IP address that you have allocated to your PC.

This should allow *anyone* to connect to the ssh server on your PC -- it is therefore vital that you secure this connection properly. There are lots of articles on how to do this ([for example](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring))